# Merging multiple text files based on one column in perl

Tags: perl, csv, merge

I am new to Perl and this is my first question in this blog hopefully to be solved.

I am having some text (10-18) files in a folder, I want to read all the files and merge all the files which are having common variables in the Names column along with their Area column for all the files. 
For example : 
file 1.txt

Name  sim  Area  Cas
aa     12   54    222
ab     23    2    343
aaa   32    34     34
bba   54     76     65

file 2.txt

Name  Sim Area  Cas
ab     45  45    56
abc    76   87    98
bba    54    87   87
aaa     33  43    54

file 3.txt

Name  Sim  Area  Cas

aaa    43   54   65
ab     544   76   87
ac     54    65   76

Output should be

Name  Area1  Area2  area3
aaa    32     43     54
ab       23   45     76

Can anyone help regarding this.  I am a very new to Perl and struggling to use Hashes.

I have tried this so far

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input_dir = 'C:/Users/Desktop/mr/';
my $output_dir = 'C:/Users/Desktop/test_output/';

opendir SD, $input_dir || die 'cannot open the input directory $!';
my @files_list = readdir(SD);
closedir(SD);

    foreach my $each_file(@files_list)
    {
        if ($each_file!~/^\./)               
        {
            #print "$each_file\n"; exit;
            open (IN, $input_dir.$each_file) || die 'cannot open the inputfile $!';
            open (OUT, ">$output_dir$each_file") || die 'cannot open the outputfile $!';

        print OUT "Name\tArea\n"; 

            my %hash; my %area; my %remaning_data;

            while(my $line=<IN>){
            chomp $line;


            my @line_split=split(/\t/,$line);
            # print $_,"\n" foreach(@line_split);

            my $name=$line_split[0]; 
             my $area=$line_split[1]; 
                }
            }   
        }
```

Can anyone provide guidance on how to complete this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lane '$X{$F[0]}.=" $F[2]";END{foreach(keys %X){if(scalar(split / /,$X{$_})==4){print $_,$X{$_}}}}' file1 file2 file3
```

tested:

```
> perl -lane '$X{$F[0]}.=" $F[2]";END{foreach(keys %X){if(scalar(split / /,$X{$_})==4){print $_,$X{$_}}}}' file1 file2 file3
ab 2 45 76
aaa 34 43 54
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $inputDir = '/tmp/input';
my $outputDir = '/tmp/out';

opendir my $readdir, $inputDir || die 'cannot open the input directory $!';
my @files_list = readdir($readdir);
closedir($readdir);

my %areas;
foreach my $file (@files_list) {
    next if $file =~ /^\.+$/; # skip ..
    open (my $fh, "<$inputDir/$file");
    while (my $s = <$fh>) {
        if ($s =~ /(\w+)\s+[\d\.]+\s+([\d\.]+)/) {
            my ($name,$area) = ($1, $2); # parse name and area
            push(@{$areas{$name}}, $area); # add area to the hash of arrays
        }
    }
    close ($fh);
}

open (my $out, ">$outputDir/outfile");
foreach my $key (keys %areas) {
    print $out "$key ";
    print $out join " ", @{$areas{$key}};
    print $out "\n";
}
close ($out);
```